# java clear a JPanel with a transparent background

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, transparent

I have been attempting to create a screen saver program. Essentially, there are multiple circles that move around the screen. However, when I make the background transparent I cannot use clearRect() anymore because that will force the background to be white. Is there any way to clear the already drawn circles while keeping the background transparent?

```
class ScreenSaver extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
static Timer t;
Ball b[];
int size = 5;

ScreenSaver() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    b = new Ball[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int x = rnd.nextInt(1400)+100;
        int y = rnd.nextInt(700)+100;
        int r = rnd.nextInt(40)+11;
        Color c = new Color(rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        int dx = rnd.nextInt(20)-10;
        if (dx == 0)
            dx++;
        int dy = rnd.nextInt(20)-10;
        if (dy == 0)
            dy++;

        b[i] = new Ball(x, y, r, c, incR, incG, incB, dx, dy);
    }
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    repaint();
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    //g.clearRect(0, 0, 1600, 900);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (b[i].x + b[i].r+b[i].dx >= 1600)
            b[i].dx *= -1;
        if (b[i].x - b[i].r+b[i].dx <= 0)
            b[i].dx *= -1;
        if (b[i].y + b[i].r+b[i].dy >= 900)
            b[i].dy *= -1;
        if (b[i].y - b[i].r+b[i].dy <= 0)
            b[i].dy *= -1;

        b[i].x += b[i].dx;
        b[i].y += b[i].dy;

        g.fillOval(b[i].x-b[i].r, b[i].y-b[i].r, b[i].r*2, b[i].r*2);
    }        
}
}
class Painter extends JFrame{
Painter() {
    ScreenSaver mySS = new ScreenSaver();
    mySS.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); //setting the JPanel transparent
    add(mySS);

    ScreenSaver.t = new Timer(100, mySS);
    ScreenSaver.t.start();

    setTitle("My Screen Saver");
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); //setting the JFrame transparent
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't call repaint() from a paint method, ever.  It will trigger another call to paint and paintComponent (eventually), creating an endless loop.  Also, do not call paintComponent directly and do not create your own Graphics.  The system does those things.  Your actionPerformed method should be calling repaint() and nothing else.

Comment: @VGR Thank you. Made those changes and its working better. Still not clearing the already drawn circles though.

Comment: What do you mean by setting the background transparent? I didn't see it in your codes.

Comment: @user3437460 mySS.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); sets the JPanel transparent and setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); sets the JFrame transparent. The forth parameter is the alpha level, from what i have read, and by setting it to 0 that makes both completely transparent without affecting what is painted in the JPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use alpha based colors with Swing components, instead, simply use `setOpaque(false)`

Change

```
mySS.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

to

```
mySS.setOpaque(false)
```

Swing only knows how to paint opaque or transparent components (via the `opaque` property)

As a personal preference, you should also be calling `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting, as your `paintComponent` really should be making assumptions about the state

Comment: Yes! This works exactly the way I was hoping it would. I'm guessing I can leave the JFrame `setBackground(new Color (0, 0, 0, 0));` the way it is since there is no `setOpaque()` option for it? (and it works...) Also where do you suggest I put the `super.paintComponent`?

Comment: Windows are the only Swing component which you can use alpha based colors with (yep, that's not confusing). Personally, I would always call `super.paintComponent` first, unless I had a very, very good reason to do otherwise

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight. The only reason I ask where to put it is because VGR commented on my original question saying I should not create my own Graphics and the only place I have a Graphics g that I can pass to `super.paintComponent` is in the paintComponent method, which he also said was something I should not do as it will loop infinitely.